# How to wire isolation relay to create C-wire

Tags: thermostat-c-wire, relay

I'm trying to follow the ecobee instructions here:
https://support.ecobee.com/hc/en-us/articles/227874527-ecobee-thermostat-installation-with-an-isolation-relay

Which uses a wiring diagram as such:
[image]
<sub>(source: [ecobee.com](https://support.ecobee.com/hc/article_attachments/360011133611/ecobee-with-isolation-relay.jpg))</sub>

I have this relay:
[image]

And here is the wiring diagram for the relay:
[image]

Can someone tell me how the ecobee diagram translates to the relay diagram? Which numbered terminals are going to T & T and which one is going to W1 and Transformer N? Thanks.

Edit:
Additional info about my specific setup.
This is the overview of my furnace:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQXam.jpg
I have the main zone which is where I want to connect the smart thermostat. I have a 2nd zone which I'm leaving alone. I have a 3rd for the water tank which I'm also leaving alone.
This is the wiring for the main zone. The T&T are in the upper right and although you can't see it there is a 3rd green wire that is currently not in use but available.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/XMC3P.jpg
main zone (aquastat) diagram:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/6zxXa.jpg
zone 2 diagram:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/kCWgh.jpg
zone 2 wiring:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/J0dzR.jpg
water heater wiring:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/DJBzs.jpg
igniter:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Jf2d.jpg

Comment: Can you post photos of the wiring at your thermostat and your boiler?

Comment: I updated with additional photos. I didn't take the thermostat apart yet. It's an old mercury honeywell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually happen to have the relay oriented in your photo the same way the relay in the diagram is oriented.

- W1 to terminal 1
- C to terminal 3
- Boiler T&T wires to 2 and 4